# How to map a TypeScript array of multiple values to Go struct

Tags: arrays, go

I'm trying to find the best way to map a TypeScript array of multiple values to a struct in Go. What do you recommend?

```
data: [number, number, number, string, string, boolean, [string, number]?][];
```

This is the data in JSON format:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      35241,
      7753,
      7750,
      "0xbb2b8038a1640196fbe3e38816f3e67cba72d940",
      "spot",
      true
    ],
    [60259, 7746, null, "#7746/USD", "internal", true, ["requote", 145]]
  ]
}
```

For now, what I'm doing is unmarshaling it into a struct using interface{}

```
Data [][]interface{} `json:"data"`
```

But then I have to do a type assertion for every field

```
for _, asset := range assetsAndPairs.Data.Pairs.Data {
    fmt.Println(asset[0].(float64))
}
```

Wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Don't think knowledge of TypeScript is needed to answer this question.

Comment: Yikes, that's rough data. First suggestion would be to try use your Typescript to more reliably sort the data types in to their own arrays before sending to Go. If it's not possible, you can go down a painful road of using Go's [Type Assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to give things a try (`try a nil -> if not nil -> try a number -> if not a number, try a string` etc.) but that road is very prickly.

Answer (score 2):

You could define your own struct with a custom unmarshal func like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

var json_data = []byte(`{
  "data": [
    [
      35241,
      7753,
      7750,
      "0xbb2b8038a1640196fbe3e38816f3e67cba72d940",
      "spot",
      true
    ],
    [60259, 7746, null, "#7746/USD", "internal", true, ["requote", 145]]
  ]
}`)

func main() {
    var doc Document
    if err := json.Unmarshal(json_data, &doc); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, r := range doc.Data {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", r)
        if r.Optional != nil {
            fmt.Printf("  with optional: %+v\n", *r.Optional)
        }
    }
}

type Document struct {
    Data []Row `json:"data"`
}

type Row struct {
    SomeInt    int
    SomeString string
    // Simplified
    Optional *MoreData
}

type MoreData struct {
    SomeString string
    SomeInt    int
}

func (row *Row) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var elements []json.RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &elements); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(elements) < 6 {
        return errors.New("too few elements")
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(elements[0], &row.SomeInt); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(elements[3], &row.SomeString); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if len(elements) == 7 {
        var more MoreData
        if err := json.Unmarshal(elements[6], &more); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        row.Optional = &more
    }

    return nil
}

func (more *MoreData) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var elements []json.RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &elements); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(elements) < 2 {
        return errors.New("too few elements")
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(elements[0], &more.SomeString); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(elements[1], &more.SomeInt); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/zLgENBZ0fkC

Based in your example data I'm assuming the `number`s are integers. If the JSON can contain floating point numbers (which would be valid `number`), you would have to adjust the type of course...

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `reflect` to define a struct with each field related to an index of `data`'s type and define the `UnmarshalJSON` function similarly to what @some-user did.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

var json_data = []byte(`{
    "data": [
      [
        35241,
        7753,
        7750,
        "0xbb2b8038a1640196fbe3e38816f3e67cba72d940",
        "spot",
        true
      ],
      [60259, 7746, null, "#7746/USD", "internal", true, ["requote", 145]]
    ]
  }`)

func main() {
    var doc Document
    if err := json.Unmarshal(json_data, &doc); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, r := range doc.Data {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", r)
        if r.G != nil {
            fmt.Printf("  with optional: %+v\n", r.G)
        }
    }
}

type Document struct {
    Data []*Row `json:"data"`
}

type Row struct {
    A int           `idx:"0"`
    B int           `idx:"1"`
    C int           `idx:"2"`
    D string        `idx:"3"`
    E string        `idx:"4"`
    F string        `idx:"5"`
    G *OptionalItem `idx:"6,optional"`
}

func (r *Row) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(r)
    val := reflect.ValueOf(r)

    return unmarshalArray(typ, val, data)
}

type OptionalItem struct {
    A string `idx:"0"`
    B string `idx:"1"`
}

func (oi *OptionalItem) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(oi)
    val := reflect.ValueOf(oi)

    return unmarshalArray(typ, val, data)
}

func unmarshalArray(typ reflect.Type, val reflect.Value, data []byte) error {
    var items []json.RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &items); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for i := 0; i < typ.Elem().NumField(); i++ {
        field := typ.Elem().Field(i)

        if value, ok := field.Tag.Lookup("idx"); ok {
            idx, optional, err := splitTag(value)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            if !optional || (optional && len(items) > idx) {
                if string(items[idx]) == "null" {
                    continue
                }

                valueField := val.Elem().FieldByName(field.Name)
                if _, ok := valueField.Interface().(json.Unmarshaler); ok {
                    if err := json.Unmarshal(items[idx], valueField.Addr().Interface()); err != nil {
                        return err
                    }
                } else {
                    if valueField.Kind() == reflect.String {
                        valueField.SetString(string(items[idx]))
                    } else if valueField.Kind() == reflect.Int {
                        number, err := strconv.Atoi(string(items[idx]))
                        if err != nil {
                            return err
                        }
                        valueField.SetInt(int64(number))
                    } else {
                        valueField.Set(reflect.ValueOf(items[idx]))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func splitTag(tag string) (idx int, optional bool, err error) {
    ops := strings.Split(tag, ",")
    if len(ops) < 1 {
        err = fmt.Errorf("empty 'idx' tag")
        return
    } else if len(ops) > 1 {
        optional = ops[1] == "optional"
    }

    idx, err = strconv.Atoi(ops[0])
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    return
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/x8hC_8JfjGG

There are still some checks missing but it does illustrates the idea.